# Have CORS requirements changed for CAF receivers?

Tags: google-cast

I am migrating from a [receiver v2](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps) to a [CAF receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_overview) (aka v3)

My understanding is that *CORS headers are not required* when streaming a media hosted on a different host than the receiver's if:

- the media is file-based (e.g. mp4)
- AND no text tracks (captions) are present with the media.

With v2, this worked as described: all my file-based media (e.g. mp4) stream just fine without the CORS headers. CORS headers are indeed needed with captioned videos or HLS

With CAF (v3) however, the receiver is complaining about missing CORS headers even with plain (no captions) mp4 video files.

Is this a bug in v3 or did I miss something from the docs?

Here is [a gist containing a simple receiver](https://gist.github.com/tifroz/04d067e0bfa53827fdd48959c51bb573) that should make it easy to reproduce the issue.

Addendum: I believe this is likely a bug, linking to the [issue I created](https://issuetracker.google.com/70411720)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the CAF receiver, a `crossorigin` attribute needs to be added to the `cast-media-player` tag to restore the old behavior

```
<cast-media-player crossorigin=""></cast-media-player>
```